# List in appwidget android

Tags: android, listview, android-appwidget

i would like to show data as list in my app widget. But i am new with app widget so can you help me with any example or any references? Here is my code:

public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider  {

```
protected static final String file_name ="user";

  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            AppWidget.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget_layout);
      //Get user name
      SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(file_name, 0);
      String name =  settings.getString("name", null);
      //Get data from database
      Database entry = new Database(context);
      entry.open();
      String[] myval=entry.planlist2(name);
      entry.close();

      // Set the text
      //remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.app_name, String.valueOf(number));
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.movie_name, Arrays.toString(myval).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppWidget.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.app_name, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }

  }

}
```

Now i want to show myval data as list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

- Add a `ListView` to your `RemoteViews` layout
- Create a `RemoteViewsService` and `RemoteViewsFactory`, basically serving in the role of what an `ArrayAdapter` might serve in a `ListView` in an activity
- Call `setRemoteAdapter()` on your `RemoteViews` to teach it where the service is to be able to populate the `ListView` rows

This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections), and [here is a sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget) demonstrating it.

Comment: how to get data from database or network in that list?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question for that.